# Prove the uniform convergence of the following function series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

Prove that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{-x}$$
is uniformly convergent on $x\in\left[a,\infty\right).$

---

According to the equality,
$$\frac{x}{1+x}<\ln(1+x)$$
we have, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{-x} &=& \exp\left\{-x\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)\right\} \\
&<& \exp\left\{-x\cdot\frac{k}{x+k}\right\}
\end{eqnarray*}

How do I control the RHS in order to apply DCT here?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \in [a,\infty)$ the summand is a monotonically decreasing function of $x$.

Note that for

$$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{-x}$$

we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = 0,\\\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+}f(x) = 1,\\f'(x) = \left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{-x}(k+x)^{-1}\left[k - (k+x)\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)\right]\leq 0$$

Hence,

$$\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{-x}\leq\left(1+\frac{k}{a}\right)^{-a}$$

If $a > 1$, by the integral test

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{a}\right)^{-a} < \infty$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^{-x}$$

converges uniformly for $1 < a \leq x$.

The series diverges if $x \leq 1$.